# Using IMultiValueConverter to pass multiple CommandParameters to viewModel

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, imultivalueconverter

I have the following code:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Security">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="Security" Content="{Binding Path=totalSecurities}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="sector"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Security" Path="Name"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Below is the code for PassThroughConverter:

```cs
public class PassThroughConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I debug as soon as it hits the return values line, the correct values are in the array
but when i press the button that triggers the filtergridcommand, the values returned are both null? Can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some experimentation confirms that doing this

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                      object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return values;
}
```

results in the command parameter ending up as `object[] { null, null }`.

The converter is run every time a bound value changes, not when the command is executed, and the return value is cached for use when the command is executed.  The original parameter `object[] values` appears to be reset to all nulls.

The solution is to clone the `values` parameter. In your case you can do this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new [] {values[0], values[1]};
}
```

More usefully, a variable number of values can be handled like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return values.ToArray();
}
```