# WPF CommandParameter MultiBinding values null

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0, multibinding

I am simply trying to bind two controls as command parameters and pass them into my command as an `object[]`.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <C:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiParamConverter"></C:MultiValueConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="Expander" Content="+" Width="25" Margin="4,0,4,0" Command="{Binding ExpanderCommand}">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiParamConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="Content"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Expander"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
            <Label FontWeight="Bold">GENERAL INFORMATION</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="Content" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Label>Test</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Command:

```
public ICommand ExpanderCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(delegate(object param)
                    {
                        var args = (object[])param;
                        var content = (UIElement)args[0];
                        var button = (Button)args[1];
                        content.Visibility = (content.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                        button.Content = (content.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? "-" : "+";
                    });
            }
        }
```

Converter:

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("No two way conversion, one way binding only.");
        }
    }
```

Basically what is happening is that the binding seems to be working fine and the converter is returning an `object[]` containing the correct values, however when the command executes the param is an `object[]` containing the same number of elements except they are `null`.

Can someone please tell me why the values of the `object[]` parameter are being set to `null`?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return values.ToArray();
}
```

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759523/using-imultivalueconverter-to-pass-multiple-commandparameters-to-viewmodel) for the explanation.