# WPF MVVM - repeated combobox, pass selectedItem as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Still getting to grips with WPF from a background in web/MVC. I've implemented something which is pretty common in UI scenarios, a repeated list of items together with some controls to allow the user to perform actions on those items (I've omitted some of the bindings because they're long relativeSource directives which are irrelevant to the question):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Counts}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{}" DisplayMemberPath="Description"></ComboBox>
                <Button Command="{}" Content="Add></Button>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"></Run>
                    <Run Text=" - "></Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can see, the ComboBox doesn't implement SelectedValue or SelectedValuePath - it can't really bind to a ViewModel property because it's repeated for each item in Counts. So at the moment it just holds a list of possible values.

The Button command binds back to a command on the ViewModel. However, in order to do anything on the button press I need to pass parameters into the command - namely, the ID of the item to which the Button is bound and whatever the user has selected in the particular ComboBox that's pair with this button.

The ID is easy - I can just bind a CommandParameter for that. But how do I pass the selected ComboBox ID into the function, and how do I ensure it's the ID from the paired ComboBox?

EDIT: A little further research suggests that while passing one CommandParameter is straightforward, passing two is not. I see answers involving converters, but in this instance my two parameters are coming from different sources, so I can't really do that. Help on how to pass both would also be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try ElementName binding?

Comment: No. I presumed it would fail because the ComboBox is in an ItemsControl, so each ComboBox would have the same Name attribute. Is that not the case?

Comment: There's a notion of a naming scope, name must be unique only withing it's naming scope.

Comment: You're quite right. It does work. Now I just have to work out how to pass both :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can pass multiple values coming from arbitrary sources  - you can take the same approach as the one used to compensate for missing `MultiBinding` in `Silverlight` - relays. The idea is very simple - create a synthetic `FrameworkElement` (herein **FE**) which will act as binding facade, I'd go for a light one - for instance `TextBlock`.

Make its `Tag` property bound to your multiple locations using `MultiBinding` and `Converter`, individual legs will be bound to the individual ElementNames. The converter will simple package up values from multiple sources and return it - it can be comma separated string, it can be an object up to you. The return of the converter will be obviously kept in the `Tag` property of your facade **FE**.

Eventually bind to the facade **FE** using `ElementName` as source and `Tag` as path.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - very much appreciated. I tried this, both multibinding to the CommandParameter direct, and your suggestion of using a Tag as a façade. However, in both cases while the converter seems to return the correct object[] values, by the time they reach the command function, it's just an array of nulls. EDIT - aha, solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713814/wpf-commandparameter-multibinding-values-null

Comment: could be because of twisted bindings or so -should work fine used countelss number of times in SL

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have the comboboxes two-way bind to a property on object class in your `counts` collection. Then the selections you make in the combos will directly alter the appropriate object, and you don't then need to manually detect/make those changes when a button is clicked.

As it stands, the type of your `counts` collection may not support that so you could create a class that added those extra properties and use those in your collection instead. Your button would then operate on the `counts` collection to create/alter data as appropriate.

Comment: The thing is collection items aren't even wrapped with VMs, they are typically a collection of models, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for a model doesn't sound like an overly good idea.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I have used a similar approach, whereby I have an ObservableCollection of some model class. That collection is then set as the ItemSource to some control, say a DataGrid, and then controls are bound to the properties of that model class. So each column, of each row, of the grid has some way to alter the value of that particular model object. The button itself is bound to a command on the VM (which the collection is a property of), and it allows you to save or reshape your collection as you see fit.